# Do web.config transformations work during build/develop cycle not just during publish?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-config-transform

I'm trying to develop my first web application using Web.Config transformations.

Trying to run the app (building with the "Dev" build configuration)in the Asp.Net Debugging web server built into VS the site doesn't seem to work - the "Web.Dev.config" configuration doesn't appear to be seen by the application.

Is this to be expected? Is it only when deploying that the transformations happen?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any asp.net web site, only web.config is examined by the web server.  web.dev.config will always be ignored (treated as nothing more than an unknown file).  This is true regardless of whether running in Visual Studio or IIS.

Comment: So it's only when you choose "Publish" that the transformations happen then?

Comment: Okay, I see that now. It makes sense too, as if the build process changed the Web.Config with an "insert", then it would keep being Inserted...